# warning: format ‘%5f’ expects type ‘double’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’

Tags: c++, opengl, floating-point, compiler-errors, printf

I'm getting (only) the following compile error:

> RuberSystem.cpp:425: warning: format ‘%5f’ expects type ‘double’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’

Here are the declarations:

```
float x = 6000.0f;
float z = -6000.0f;
float lx = -6000.0f;
float lz = 6000.0f;
float angle = 0.0f;
```

and here's line 425:

```
printf("Right pressed: angle=%5f\nx=%5f\nlx=%5f\nz=%5f\nlz=%5f",angle,x,lx,z,lz);
```

The only operations these variables undergo are:

```
angle -= 0.01f;
lx = sin (angle);
lz = -cos (angle);
```

I tried casting these operations with (float) as well, and with no luck.

Possibly useful info: This worked on my windows machine, in Visual Studio 8, and now I'm compiling on my macbook w/ GNU g++. I've already set the proper definitions for mac use.

edit: I found one more operation on these variables:

```
gluLookAt(
  x, 1500.0, z,    // eye location
  x+lx, 0.0,   z+lz,    // center location
  0.0, 1.0,   0.0); //open GL function
```

I took a look at the code for gluLookAt and it appears to take in floats and store them in a matrix of floats, so I don't see the problem being there either, yet I thought it would be a good thing to share.

**Answer:** I'm an idiot. The method that was calling `angle -= 0.01f;...` had arguments named `int x` and `int y`, thusly `void processSpecialKeys(int key, int x, int y) {`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The lines that you have shown us look ok. I presume the problem is in the lines that you *haven't* shown us. Please reduce your original program to the smallest possible program that still demonstrates the error, and copy-paste that program into your question. See http://sscce.org for more details.

Comment: Are you maybe redeclaring `x` somewhere as type `int`?

Comment: This sounds like some compiler error to me (some optimization gone wrong?) What happens if you're using any non-integer variable, e.g. `6000.1f`? Also have you tried different compiler versions?

Comment: @Mario: I think it's *highly* unlikely to be a problem with the compiler.

Comment: @Jake Cohen: Well, what you posted so far will not by itself produce this error. Post more code. Try reducing your code while keeping an eye on the warning.

Comment: The fact that the compiler doesn't complain for the `gluLookAt()` call doesn't really tell us anything.  The prototype for `gluLookAt()` will cause the compiler to automatically convert an `int` argument to a `float` (assuming that the corresponding `gluLookAt()` argument is of type `float`).  that will not happen for the `varargs` part of the arguments passed to `printf()`.

Comment: Answer: I'm an idiot. The method that was calling angle -= 0.01f;... had arguments named int x and int y, thusly: void processSpecialKeys(int key, int x, int y) {.

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: It happens. Sometimes the most obvious errors become sort of invisible.

Comment: If you found the answer yourself, post this as an answer to your question and accept it. That's the canonical way to mark questions self-answered on StackOverflow.

Comment: @datenwolf As a new member, I can't answer questions within 8 hours of them being asked, until I have a reputation of 10.

Comment: @JakeCohen: Just wait for this amount of time

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a different declaration of `x` in effect at line 425? For example:

```
float x;
void func(int x) { ... }

// or

float x;

for (int x = ...)
{
}

// or

#define x ...
```

Comment: no I don't. it's strange

Comment: Don't think so. A redefinition of a already known name, especially with a different datatype, should cause an error, not just a warning (so the compiler continues).

Comment: @Mario Without seeing the larger context it can't be ruled out. It's possible to re-use variable names in nested scopes. Local variables hide global variables and function parameters.

Comment: @Mario: Not true, if the definition is made in a different scope. I'm sure this is what John meant in his answer.

Comment: You're right, forgot about scopes.

Comment: If I remember correctly, gcc's format warning counts the arguments from 1 and #1 is actually the format string itself. So, #3 in this case is `x`, not `lx`.

Comment: Answer: I'm an idiot. The method that was calling angle -= 0.01f;... had arguments named int x and int y, thusly: void processSpecialKeys(int key, int x, int y) {.

Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:** The method that was calling angle `-= 0.01f;...` had arguments named `int x` and `int y`, thusly: `void processSpecialKeys(int key, int x, int y) {`. Thank you all for the help.